# Send a Signal to a child process after a certain period of time

Tags: c, timer, fork, exec

I was just wondering whether anybody knew how to track the time for how long a child process has been running in C? I'm launching many child processes at once using fork() but if they do not exit after a certain period of time I want to send them a SIGABRT signal.
E.g., if I have a child process that does the following so it sleeps for 10 seconds.

```
if (!fork()) {
    execlp("sleep", "sleep", "10", NULL);
}
```

If I wanted to send a SIGBRT to this after say 5 seconds how could I go about doing this? I have multiple processes to manage so I'm not sure how to keep track of how long each process has been running for.

Comment: There are many ways to structure the code so it is difficult to provide a general solution. A basic approach would be to keep a list of child processes that includes the abort time for each process. Keep the list sorted by next abort time. Then in the monitoring process create a `signalfd` to catch `SIGCHLD` signals that indicate child process termination and `poll` those with a timeout. The timeout would be set based on the next abort time.